# Load Text File data in Combobox for WPF application in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

How to load items in Combo box from a text file? The text file has one item per line. 
I tried to load data to a string and set the *Itemsource* with the string

`string path = @"E:\Testing\WPF_school\WPF_school\Nationality.txt";
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllText(path);`

Comment: I have added an ItemSource in it. But couldn't able to retrieve data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- load the text from your file in a list of string
- set the itemssource of your combobox to your list with binding (when mvvm) or codebehind

ps: if you want some code post yours first and i edit my answer

Comment: I was using `string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);` to read and set itemsource as _readtext_